# jqGrid afterclickPgButtons bind?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use jqGrid 4.9.3-pre - free(Oleg). I do not use `navbar panel`. How do I get at `Ajax` after `afterclickPgButtons`?

I found a lot of similar themes, but almost all the navbar to panel. [similar question, but `jqGridAddEditAfterClickPgButtons` callback I not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877528/struts2-jqgrid-bind-afterclickpgbuttons-to-edit-dialog/30883062)

```js
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    $(this).jqGrid("viewGridRow", rowid, {
        beforeShowForm: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'apt_data.php',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {id: rowid},
                success: function(data) {
                    $(html_var).insertBefore($('#trv_tm', form));
                }
            });
        },
        caption: "Details of the invice"
    });     
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have some close to [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877528/struts2-jqgrid-bind-afterclickpgbuttons-to-edit-dialog/30883062), but with `viewGridRow`, then you need just change the name of jQuery event to `jqGridViewBeforeShowForm` and `jqGridViewAfterclickPgButtons`. You can use `jqGridViewClickPgButtons` which will be triggered before `jqGridViewAfterclickPgButtons`, but it will be needed more seldom:

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    // ...
}).bind ("jqGridViewBeforeShowForm", function (e, $form, oper) {
    alert("In jqGridViewAfterShowForm");
}).bind ("jqGridViewClickPgButtons", function (e, whichButton, $form, rowid) {
    alert("In jqGridViewClickPgButtons: " + whichButton + ", rowid=" + rowid);
}).bind ("jqGridViewAfterclickPgButtons", function (e, whichButton, $form, rowid) {
    alert("In jqGridViewAfterclickPgButtons: " + whichButton + ", rowid=" + rowid);
});
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/cnyon3tt/2/